# Экспорт и импорт данных из 1 колонки в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Добрый вечер.

Есть интернет-магазин, несколько тысяч товаров. Есть таблица products в БД MySQL, соответственно.

Задача: нужно изменить описание у каждого товара. Надо выгрузить данные из 1 поля description в какой то удобно редактируемый вид с возможностью дальнейшего импорта обратно.

Возможно ли это?

Comment: проще выгрузить всю таблицу в csv, исправить description, грохнуть таблицу, залить обратно.

Comment: Кроме description есть еще куча полей, будет слишком неудобно

Comment: @waid, в Excel'е можно спрятать лишние колонки, будет аналогично как если бы вы выгрузили одну или две колонки. "слишком неудобно" не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не съехали описания при расчете просто на порядок строк, я бы вывел, как минимум, две колонки: *id, описание*.

Эти данные в csv или даже Excel отдаёте Васе-фрилансеру для перевода, тёте Маше для литературной правки и т.п. Результат трудов затем импортируете простеньким скриптом, который пробежит по каждой строчке, обновляя в базе опсиание по *id*. Или испортируете в новую временную таблицу, и обновляете основную по ключу.